# How to shard across a cluster of nodes based on the value of String?

Tags: java, sharding, distributed-system, ignite

I would like to create a distributed system where the data is sharded across all the nodes. I know there are libraries like Hazelcast or Apache Ignite that do the work for you. In my case, for each sharding key I need to create a socket subscription to another system so it's not just about how data is distributed but also how to actually create these subscriptions in a distributed way.

The idea is to, for each sharding key, create a subscription to the other system. Each subscription would keep a list of entries with data to check for every update coming from the socket connection.

What I had in mind was to send, for each new entry to keep, a message with the sharding key and the data to a topic. Then each node would apply the sharding algorithm to decide which of them is responsible to process the message and then create the subscription to the socket connection if it's not there already and add the data to it.

The complexity with this is to handle cluster topology changes. I would need to rebalance these connections manually by letting one node act as a leader reloading the data from database and resending the data again. Nodes would also need to react to these changes clearing the subscriptions. For that I thought of using a version number that would go alongside the data which increases with every change and allows nodes to identify these changes. Another solution would be to make every node aware of topology changes through events but these are async so I could run into race conditions when clearing the subscriptions.

Is there any other way or a better one of doing this? Maybe with some of the features Ignite provides? (I'm using Ignite for a cache in this case)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a use case for continuous queries: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/continuous-queries

Comment: Can you elaborate on this, please? For what I understand from reading the documentation, I would need to create: 1- a query with the sharding algorithm to load current data. 2- a filter with the same sharding algorithm for new entries. 3- a listener to the entries that pass the filter once everything is already started. 4- code to process the entries that pass the initial query. With this I would make sure only one node executes my logic for every entry. Is this correct? How would I handle topology changes? I would need to start over for every change in the cluster.

Comment: First of all, Ignite doesn't do sharding. It partitions the data based on the per-key level based on affinity function. Continuous query allows a node to listen for cache updates that happen anywhere in the cluster, with the optional filter on the server side (you can put any logic you like there). Topology changes are handled automatically in case you have backups.